# Crash at minimize window & closing document COM AddIn

Tags: c#, ms-word, com

I try to minimize and close a document inside the DocumentBeforeClose event-method. But if i do so, there is a chance that word crashes. Not every time, but reproducable.

I builded a very simplified version of my addin. It contains only the registration of the event and the event-method itself:

```
public void OnConnection(object application, Extensibility.ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref System.Array custom)
{
      //Apply Application
      m_ApplicationObject = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)application;

      //Register event
      m_ApplicationObject.DocumentBeforeClose += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentBeforeCloseEventHandler(m_ApplicationObject_DocumentBeforeClose);                    
}

private void m_ApplicationObject_DocumentBeforeClose(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document Doc, ref bool cancel)
{
     //Close Document. If you do so, the Word-Window will stay open! WINWORD.EXE will not exit!
     object doNotSaveChanges = MSword.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
     object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;                
     Doc.Close(ref doNotSaveChanges, ref missing, ref missing);

     //Minimize Word-Window.         
     m_ApplicationObject.WindowState = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMinimize;
}
```

The crash appears at Word 2016. I could not test older versions.

How to reproduce:
Open a random word document. Click on the 'X' to close. The document will closing and word will minimizing. Restore word and open a random document, clickt 'X' to close... Repeat this 2-5 times and the crash will occure.

Comment: The code is jerking the floor mat.  At least use cancel = true so Word doesn't try to close a document that is already closed.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks a lot! cancel = true sloved the problem! But i'm still confused a bit... Why is it a problem for word, when i'm trying to minimize the window? If i don't minimize, there occures no crash... Because of this, i didn't thought on cancel = true...